# CTE not working with extra join clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Can someone tell me why this returns 0 records when I add the extra join information for [PropertyId]? I know this is something simple but, I'm at a loss.

```
declare @ViewId as int;

set @ViewId = 11;

with Views
as
(
    select [LiveWireView].[Id], [LiveWireView].[Name], [LiveWireView].[ParentId], [PropertyToViewMap].[PropertyId]
    from [LiveWireView]
    inner join [PropertyToViewMap] on [PropertyToViewMap].[ViewId] = [LiveWireView].[Id]
    where [LiveWireView].[Id] = @ViewId
    union all
    select [v].[Id], [v].[Name], [v].[ParentId], [p].[PropertyId]
    from [LiveWireView] v
    inner join [PropertyToViewMap] p on [p].[ViewId] = [v].[Id]
    inner join Views on Views.Id = v.ParentId
)

select [PropertyId] from Views;
```

Comment: Could you please create a sample on [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)?

Comment: Do you get results from this?: SELECT * FROM PropertyToViewMap WHERE ViewId = 11

Answer (score 0):

If you added this join:

```
inner join [PropertyToViewMap] p on [p].[ViewId] = [v].[Id]
```

And are no longer getting results, I think it's same to say that there are no records that meet these conditions.  You could test this by converting it to a `LEFT JOIN` and seeing if you get a null value for `PropertyId`

Comment: If I change that line to a left join I get this error:

Outer join is not allowed in the recursive part of a recursive common table expression 'Views'.

Comment: Sounds like you can't do a left join in a recursive CTE.  Well you can't really test my theory, but I still stand by it.  If nothing is being returned and the only thing you have added was the INNER JOIN, then there is nothing matching that criteria.

Comment: No, you are very correct. During certain recursions there will be no results. I still need the query to work though so that I can select all PropertyId's that belong to a view where views are in a hierarchy. This has really got me stumped.

Comment: Well I don't think that it's that your join will exclude certain records from your results, but rather that 100% of the records you want are not meeting the joins condition.  Could you post a small set of your data and the desired result?

Comment: And you could leave PropertyToViewMap out of the Views CTE, but SELECT ... FROM Views v LEFT OUTER JOIN PropertyToViewMap p on p.ViewId = v.Id in the main query.